# psycopg installation success, but cannot be imported in VSCode (import error)

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, psycopg2

I apologize if this has been asked before, but on the review page, I couldn't find a similar situation. I'm new to using psycopg2 and pip (as an installer in general). I attempted to install psycopg2 today (through VSCode terminal) but when I tried to import it, it said that the module didn't exist.

[Error Image from VSCode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/szBvp.png)

I've checked the library and it appears in there. I've made sure to try both versions (psycopg2 and psycopg2_binary). I had to update my pip to the newest version, but I've installed and reinstalled both of the psycopg2 versions with no change to the error message.

[Proof of installation through VSCode terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5wFNc.png)

I'm currently on Windows, but I'm not sure if that would make a difference.

Thanks for any help!

Edit: I was asked about the change in file between C: and Z: drive in the photos.
To remove any issue of this, I moved the .py file with psycopg2 on it into the directory and ran the queries again

[Starter.py being in Python directory on C:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TENDZ.png)
[Starter.py being in C://Downloads](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OWwMR.png)

I included the downloads picture as this was where starter.py was originally, but also just incase there was issues with it being in the actual python directory folder.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that you are using the right python kernel to execute the starter.py?
Your python installation is located in "C:", but you are executing something in a "Z:" drive. Pip should be pretty straight foward when installing this kind of package.

Open a terminal and type **python**. After that type

> import psycopg2

and hit enter. If this line doesn't output an error, than the package is correct installed and probably you are not using the correct python kernel inside VSCode.

Comment: Hi. It's because I have 2 drives on my computer, my ssd and harddrive. Python is installed on the ssd (C:) while starter.py was on the harddrive (Z:). I moved starter.py to my C drive, putting it in the python folder, but again I still have the import error. I've included pictures above just for clarification

Answer (score 0):

After installing and reinstalling Python numerous times, I have (I think) finally installed psycopg2!

For those curious, it appeared that I had 2 script pathways in Windows. Essentially, Python was taking the first one, which was incorrect, and non-existent (old version of Python I installed at like 15 and subsequently deleted), and this was causing the error. This also caused problems with pip. My solution is therefore this.

1. Install Python, and take note of the installation folder (You'll need it)
2. Go to the properties of My Computer or This PC
3. Click on Advanced System Settings
4. Click on Environmental Variables
5. Select "Path" then hit edit.
6. Look for the pathway that your Python was insatalled on. Make sure it reads something along the lines of PythonX\Scripts (with X being substituted for your version!).
7. If there are more \Script routes with Python, delete them, and move the correct route to the top of the Pathways.

That's it! You should now be able to run the installation of psycopg, and test that it imports correctly as I did in VSCode!

Proof of Psycopg2 installation after proposed solution:
[image: Proof of Psycopg2 installation after proposed solution]
Proof of no errors when Psycopg2 is imported:
[image: Proof of no errors when Psycopg2 is imported]

Answer (score 0):

After the latest VSCode update (Jan, 2022), the recommended python interpreter has been changed from the 64-bit version of the latest python version installed in your computer to the 64-bit version of the python pyenv installed in yoru computer. To resolve this importing problem, change the preference setting from this recommended one to the global one. Sometimes you can see it on the bottom left corner of the VSCode app when you open the file. Changing that preference allowed me to import the module correctly.

Answer (score 0):

install Python enviroment manager (extension) then go to the extension and change (set new eviroment) or look out the eviroment that contains the packages.

that works for me